# How to make border radius smooth and circular in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, button, border-radius

I am trying to understand the underlying concept in button shape styling.

For example
BorderRadius.circular(12)
and
BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))
[Here is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cW8Go.png)

Both seem do the same thing and yet there are two options. Am I missing something. I am working on this tool [vidution.com](https://vidution.com/).

I am trying to make these 8 edges smoother and circular but these edges are sharp . How can I do that with elevated button.

Here is the sample code

```
class ButtonBorderRadius extends StatefulWidget {
  const ButtonBorderRadius({super.key});

  @override
  State<ButtonBorderRadius> createState() => _ButtonBorderRadiusState();
}

class _ButtonBorderRadiusState extends State<ButtonBorderRadius> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: const Text('Interactive Viewer Example'), centerTitle: true),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12)),
              ),
              child: const Text('Beveled Rectangle Border -> Radius Circular'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 24),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                shape: const BeveledRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(12))),
              ),
              child: const Text('Beveled Rectangle Border -> Radius All Circular'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: tried to `ctrl-click` on `BorderRadius.circular` constructor (to be more precise on `circular` part)?